If you say/said..., then it means/would mean
Person A: in the morning my friend asked how I got to work today. I replied "on a cab". He said it should be "in a cab". Why?

Person B: if you said (=were to say) you got to work on a cab, it would mean that you were sitting on the roof of the cab during the journey. (B replies with a hypothetical if-sentence)

Person B: if you said (=did say) you got to work on a cab, it meant/means that you were sitting on the roof of the cab during the journey. (B replies with a real past if-sentence)

Person B: if you say you got to work on a cab, it means that you were sitting on the roof of the cab during the journey. (B replies with a real present + real past if-sentence)

Person B: if you say you get to work on a cab, it means that you are sitting on the roof of the cab during the journey. (B replies with a real present if-sentence)


Questions:
(1) which one(s) of the B sentences can be said as a response?
(2) of sentences 2, 3 and 4, which is the real equivalent of hypothetical sentence 1, in terms of tense?

2 and 3 are just daft. 1 and 4 mean different things, so there's no "best" version. It's all contrived anyway. We get to work in a car or on a bus or train, but it would probably be by taxi/cab (and by air rather than in a plane).

How are 1 and 4 different? I don't understand.

1 can refer to a single occasion (a contextually implied "real" instance, or just a single non-specifiic example day's commute). But 2 can only really refer to regular repeated action.

You say "1 can refer to a contextually implied "real" instance". Can I say that, in this meaning, the past tense verbs said (=were to say) and would both have hypothetical meaning (hypothetical markers), whereas the past tense verbs got and were refer to the actual event that took place in the morning? In other words, in sentence 1, we can see a mix of verbs with hypothetical and real references/meanings.

... continued...then you say "1 can also refer to just a single non-specific example day's commute". Can I say that, in this meaning, all four verbs, viz, said (=were to say), got, would and were have hypothetical/unreal references/meanings? None of them is referring to the actual event that took place in the morning.

Yes. The the past tense verbs said (=were to say) and would do indeed both have "hypothetical meaning", because they're modified by initial If... But the referent of the got to work element in #1 could be contextually deemed to mean got to work this morning (or like I said, it could refer to "any unspecified day, that may or may not have actually occurred").

Thank you ... just one last question: you said in your comment #1 "sentences 2 and 3 are just daft". May I know why you think so?

They're just random mixtures of verb tenses. Some combinations could be considered "coherent" (it's feasible they could be making meaningful assertions in unusual contexts), but for you as a non-native speaker it's simply not worth going into scenarios that are difficult to describe and will probably never arise in the real world. For your purposes, I think it's enough to just say 2 & 3 are "invalid". You won't learn anything useful about normal English by being told about some contrived context where a peculiar combination of verb tenses might be "parsable" by a native Anglophone.

Sentences 1 & 2 have the if clause 'if you said '. Person A had already said it so these two cannot be true.
Sentence 4 has 'get to work' which means on a daily basis.
So only Sentence 3 is correct:- If you say you got to work on a cab, it means that you were sitting on the roof of the cab during the journey
